# Type Inference for std::string in Template Function Fails

Tags: c++, string, templates, vector

I am trying to learn c++ templates. One function in a script compiles, whilst a seemingly similar function fails. The entire script is:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

template <typename T>
void works(vector<int>& vi, vector<double>& vd, vector<T>& inp) {
    if (std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        vd.push_back(inp[0]);
    else if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        vi.push_back(inp[0]);
}

template <typename T>
void doesnt_work(vector<std::string>& vs, vector<double>& vd, vector<T>& inp) {
    if (std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        vd.push_back(inp[0]);
    else if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        vs.push_back(inp[0]);  // Line 18:  no matching member function
}

int main() {
    vector<double> d = {2, 3, 4};
    vector<double> doubles;
    vector<std::string> strings;
    vector<int> ints;
    doesnt_work(strings, doubles, d);  // Line 26: Comment out and script runs
    works(ints, doubles, d);
    return 0;
}
```

The function `works` takes the two vectors `vi` and `vd` containing `int` and `double` as references, as well as a third vector with elements of type T. I then try to check for the type of `T` and push the first element of the vector `inp` into either `vi` or `vd`. In contrast, the function `doesnt_work` causes problems. Instead of accepting a vector of `int` as parameter, it accepts a vector of `std::string`. I can run the entire script when I comment out line 26. Otherwise, `clang++` tells me that

```cpp
error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
        vs.push_back(inp[0]);
```

Does somebody kindly have any idea what I am doing wrong? I do not understand why the program cannot access the function `push_back` of the vector `vs`.

Comment: offtopic: if it is only either `double`s or `string`s using simple overloads  is sufficient

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion does indeed work. However, if I generalize the script the program fails again. For example, if I change the input `inp` to be a `vector` of `string` instead of a `vector` of `double` the other branch of the if statement in `doesnt_work` causes problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void now_works(vector<std::string>& vs, vector<double>& vd, vector<T>& inp) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same<T, double>::value)
    vd.push_back(inp[0]);
  else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    vs.push_back(inp[0]);  // Line 18:  no error
}
```

your problem is that all branches are compiled even if they aren't run.

`if constexpr` makes them compiled, then discards them at compile time, ignoring any type errors.

The code that worked, everything could convert even if not run, so it compiled.

The code that didn't work, the conversion you wanted to exclude is illegal, so it failed at compile time.

Note that `if constexpr` only works because the branching clause is a compile-time constant, and because it is in a template, and the clause is dependent on the template parameters, and the code that is invalid is also dependent on the template parameters.

If you don't have `if constexpr` yet because you are stuck on an old version of C++, you will be forced to do something ugly like tag dispatching or SFINAE with helper functions or something more arcane.

Comment: @Yaak, thanks for your kind and detailed answer. There's a lot to learn for me from that.